# QC10 with Windows7 and VAPI-XP Scripts

Tags: testing, jar, hp-quality-center

I'm currently trying to execute VAPI-XP scripts through QC10 on a Windows7 PC and running into problems whereby I cannot execute them due to Error:Unexpected statement, furthermore I am unable to open the test script tab without QC10 explorer freezing for a few minutes then displaying "!!! Error: Unexpected Statement" instead of the VBSCRIPT code.

This problem does not occur on other PCs and I can access them properly via Test Plan Tree, viewing the Test Script tab under + executing them as a .jar file through Test Lab.

I've done extensive research, some results containing the deletion of DCOM registry files which I have tried but instead get another error after doing so. The release notes on QC10 Patch 12 explains that the execution of VAPI-XP scripts via QC10 on Windows 7 is broken, however we are currently running patch 22... I believe it is up to patch 29 currently however this is not an option as updating it will require updating the QC on all computers at work.

Initially, I thought it was only a QC10 compatibility issue with windows 7, however the odd thing is that it has been tested and working on another PC with QC10(same patch) and Windows 7 - It is able to access and view the Test script tab under test plan tree as well as executing it under Test lab. But not on the PC I am using.

Could anyone please advise on a solution or an idea on how to solve this issue that does not include updating the QC10 patch?

Thanks, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you have installed the Connectivity add-in on the PC in question.  It is available on the add-ins page of the server.